# django missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'manager'

Tags: django, django-admin

Tengo el siguiente error al acceder al modelo "Norma" a través del administrador django. "*missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'manager'*"

**El error completo es el siguiente:**

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/norma/norma/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 278, in lookup_field
    f = _get_non_gfk_field(opts, name)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 313, in _get_non_gfk_field
    raise FieldDoesNotExist()
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 156, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 154, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\base.py", line 33, in render
    return super().render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py", line 214, in render
    _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py", line 341, in result_list
    'results': list(results(cl))}
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py", line 318, in results
    yield ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None))
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py", line 309, in __init__
    super().__init__(*items)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py", line 228, in items_for_result
    f, attr, value = lookup_field(field_name, result, cl.model_admin)
  File "C:\Users\Acevedo Duran\Documents\Desarrollos\PT2\Competence Check 001\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 291, in lookup_field
    value = attr()
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'manager'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from app.eje_curricular.models import Eje_curricular
from app.taxonomia.models import Taxonomia

# Create your models here.

class Norma(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    abreviatura = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    organizacion = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    descripcion = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    activa_en_eje = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    eje = models.ForeignKey(Eje_curricular, related_name='normas' ,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    taxonomia = models.OneToOneField(Taxonomia, related_name='norma' ,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, null=True)
    lastModification = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
import django_filters.rest_framework
from .models import *
from .serializers import *

# Create your views here.

class NormaList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Norma.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NormaSerializer
    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = (
        'id',
        'nombre', 
        'abreviatura',
        'competencias', 
        'organizacion', 
        'descripcion',
        'taxonomia', 
        'eje' , 
        'timestamp', 
        'lastModification', 
        )

class NormaDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Norma.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NormaSerializer
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

# Register your models here.

class NormaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'nombre', 
        'abreviatura', 
        'organizacion', 
        'descripcion', 
        'taxonomia',
        'competencias',
        'activa_en_eje', 
        'eje' ,
        'timestamp', 
        'lastModification', 
        )
    class Meta:
        model = Norma
admin.site.register(Norma, NormaAdmin)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Norma
from app.categoria.models import Categoria

class NormaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    categorias = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='categoria-detail'
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Norma
        fields = (
            'id',
            'nombre', 
            'abreviatura', 
            'organizacion', 
            'descripcion', 
            'categorias' ,
            'taxonomia',
            'competencias',
            'activa_en_eje', 
            'eje', 
            'timestamp', 
            'lastModification', 
            )
```

No muestra ningún error al hacer las migraciones, sólo al acceder al administrador del backend.

alguna idea?
Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fué un problema con el campo "competencias" en la clase Admin, el modelo Competencia tiene una foránea al modelo Norma.

Lo solucioné al crear el "Inline" del modelo "Competencia".

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
from app.competencia.models import Competencia

# Register your models here.

class CompetenciaInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Competencia

class NormaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'nombre', 
        'abreviatura', 
        'organizacion', 
        'descripcion', 
        'taxonomia',
        # 'competencias',
        'activa_en_eje', 
        'eje' ,
        'timestamp', 
        'lastModification', 
        )
    # filter_horizontal = (
    #     'competencias',
    # )
    inlines = [CompetenciaInline]
    class Meta:
        model = Norma
admin.site.register(Norma, NormaAdmin)
```